# Flow in bend pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

What happens to a flow in a bent pipe of uniform cross sectional area? Will there be any change in flow velocity at the outlet? If yes, why does it happen? What happens at the bent area of the pipe? Please answer in layman's terms.

Comment: If it is an (incompressible) liquid, there will be no change in the flow velocity at the outlet because mass has to be conserved.

Answer (score 0):

For the fluid to negotiate the bend will require work due to the inertial forces as well as the friction, so there is a pressure loss.

Even a straight length of pipe has a pressure loss due to the friction of the fluid against the surface of the pipe.